# Delete a users post using ajax and js in laravel 5.4

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I'm new to Laravel. I am trying to create a common social network. 
    Now I want to be able to delete a user's post. At the moment when you try to submit the form it loads the ajax 
    but can not delete the data.

**Here is my code:**

```
$("#_global_modal").delegate('#modal_form_delete', 'submit', 
 function(event) 
 {
    // To stop a form default behaviour
    event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({ 
       url: $(this).attr('action'),               
       type: $(this).attr('method'), 
       dataType: 'json',
       data: $(this).serialize(),
   })
    .done(function(response){
        if(response.delete == "success"){
            window.location.href = response.redirect_route
        }else{
            console.log(response);
        }
    })
    .fail(function(){
        console.log("error");
    })
    .always(function(){
        console.log("complete");
    });

});
```

Route:

```
Route::post('delete','crude@delete')->name('delete');
```

My controller part:

```
public function delete(Request $request)
{
    if($request->ajax()){
       $user = Auth::user();
       $user->post()->delete(['post' => $request->post]);

       return response()->json([
                'delete'            =>  'success',
                'redirect_route'    =>  route('profile')
            ]);

    }else{
        return response()->json([
            'delete'            =>  'ERROR',
            'ERROR_MSG'    =>  'ERROR MSG'
        ]);
        dd("Sorry you have to send your form information by using ajax 
      request");
    }
}

 So how can I solve this problem?
```

Comment: What does `$request->post` contain? The post id?

Comment: Yes, it's user's post id.

Answer (score 1):

Your delete statement is wrong.

```
public function delete(Request $request)
{
    if($request->ajax()) {
        Post::where('id', $request->post)
            ->where('user_id', auth()->id())
            ->delete();

        return response()->json([
            'delete' =>  'success',
            'redirect_route' =>  route('profile')
        ]);
    }

    return response()->json([
        'delete' =>  'ERROR',
        'ERROR_MSG' =>  'ERROR MSG'
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Can not delete the data, it sends to the else segment of the controller.